# Rails with Savon over HTTPS: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wsdl, savon

I am using Savon to connect to a web service endpoint via HTTP without issue. I can do this via SoapUI and via Savon. I now have to hit an HTTPS endpoint. I was able to do this with SoapUI (without providing any additional authentication credentials), but when I attempt to connect via Savon, I am getting a "SocketError: Connection reset by peer". My code is simple:

client = Savon.client(wsdl: "/ws/services/mainservice?wsdl")

client.operations

As you can see I am simply trying to display the available operations. Am I missing something here? Is SoapUI doing somthing "under the covers" that I need to do to the Savon client object?

Note: One thing to note is that when I point SoapUI to the wsdl, all is correct save for the endpoint on an individual request. This is "Http" rather than "https". Changing this though makes things work as expected, still without implicitly providing credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the client tries to verify the SSL certificate. Hence you haven't given one it fails. You might try this:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "/ws/services/mainservice?wsdl",
                      ssl_verify_mode: :none)

client.operations
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Probably should have posted that I did. Thanks though.